# how to prevent one of the inputs of a form from submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have a form with several inputs in it

in a specific time when a checkbox gets checked, I don't want one of the inputs to be submitted and others get to submit.

how can I prevent one of the inputs from submission?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Comment: Use javascript to detect when the checkbox is checked and modify the form accordingly.

Comment: how ????? i want to prevent only one input

Comment: can you update the code which you done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example <--- Please read this article and update your post accordingly. You will get a more desirable result in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form. Just remove the name attribute of your input.
for more info look at this article in [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp)